# In expl3, how to test if something, once fully expanded, contains any character belonging to classes 11 or 12?

Tags: expl3, expansion, programming

I am wondering in `expl3` syntax (not using the most recent additions, let's say additions posteriors to 2018 [nothing special about 2018, it's just an arbitrary date to say *not too recent*]) how to test if something **once fully expanded** contains **any character that belongs to classes 11 or 12**?

```
\documentclass[preview = true, varwidth = true]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mytest}{m m m}{
    % CODE HERE
}

\newcommand{\myempty}{}
\newcommand{\mywhitespace}{ }
\newcommand{\myquad}{\qquad}
\newcommand{\myrelax}{\relax}
\newcommand{\mystring}{ x }

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\mytest{\myempty}{true}{false} \\        % false
\mytest{\mywhitespace}{true}{false} \\   % false
\mytest{\myquad}{true}{false} \\         % false
\mytest{\myrelax}{true}{false} \\        % false
\mytest{\mystring}{true}{false} \\       % true
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

If I use `\tl_if_blank:nTF`, it does not work:

```
\documentclass[preview = true, varwidth = true]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_blank:nTF{eTF}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mytest}{m m m}{\tl_if_blank:eTF{#1}{#3}{#2}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\myempty}{}
\newcommand{\mywhitespace}{ }
\newcommand{\myquad}{\qquad}
\newcommand{\myrelax}{\relax}
\newcommand{\mystring}{ x }

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\mytest{\myempty}{true}{false} \\      % false: OK
\mytest{\mywhitespace}{true}{false} \\ % false: OK
\mytest{\myquad}{true}{false} \\       % true: PROBLEM
\mytest{\myrelax}{true}{false} \\      % true: PROBLEM
\mytest{\mystring}{true}{false} \\     % true: OK
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \tl_if_blank:nTF ?

Comment: What is so special about 2018?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Returns `false`, `false`, `true`, `true`, `true`,

Comment: Your test is ambiguous: `\relax` and `\qquad` are not characters, and certainly can't be regarded as equal to say an ASCII space

Comment: One can image for example doing a full expansion then using a loop to check if the 'balance' is made up of chars of Unicode category Zs, but as there are only 17 of those, you would likely be best hard-coding (also, the test for Unicode category is pretty new).

Comment: Basically I think what I want to test is if the expanded argument contains anything of latex character classes 11, 12, (and maybe 13, but I'm not sure what character class 13 actually contains)?

Comment: @Vincent Still ambiguous - for example, in a Unicode engine U+2009 (thin space) is valid input, will be catcode 12 but I suspect you want to treat as 'blank'. Either way, please edit the question to make this clearer.

Comment: imho you are confusing input and printed output. glue like `\quad` is not a "character". What e.g. would you want to get from the input `ab`  if the current font contains a ligature that replaces that by a space?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I edited the question to make it clearer. I actually do not care about output/printability for my problem. Defining it as classes 11 and 12, is enough for me.

Comment: But the expansion of `\quad` for example does contain tokens with category 11 and 12, you can check that with `\tl_set:Ne\l_tmpa_tl{#1}\tl_analysis_show:N\l_tmpa_tl` in your command. So why do you think you should get false there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we can treat brace groups at the top level only, anbd that `{E}` is equivalent to `E`, then we can do

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \vincent_if_blank:n #1 { p , T , F , TF }
  { \exp_args:Ne \__vincent_if_blank:n {#1} }
\cs_new:Npn \__vincent_if_blank:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nTF {#1}
      { \prg_return_true: }
      {
        \tl_map_function:nN {#1} \__vincent_if_blank_aux:n
        \prg_return_true:    
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__vincent_if_blank_aux:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_single_token:nTF {#1}
      {
        \bool_lazy_or:nnT
          { \token_if_letter_p:N #1 }
          { \token_if_other_p:N #1 }
          { \tl_map_break:n { \use_i:nn \prg_return_false: } }
      }
      { \tl_map_break:n { \use_i:nn \prg_return_false: } }
      
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mytest}{m m m}{\vincent_if_blank:nTF{#1}{#3}{#2}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Refinement to brace handling is possible, but the question does not clearly define the expectations in this areas.

The problem is made more tricky something like `\qquad` expands to `\hskip 2em\relax`, and that then does contain catcode-11 and 12 tokens. If we assume that such cases can be covered by

```latex
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\qquad
```

then we can proceed to get the desired outputs with the code suggested.